# Unity c# Array index is out of range

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

hi guys i'm making a cube swapping game for my project at uni and i have a problem where my code tries to access an array address that doesnt exist, though im not sure how its accessing it. for some reason on the second or third pass it sets l,m and n to 5 and as my array is only 5x5x5 units long it cant find anything.

```
public void matchCheck()
{ 
      int l;
      int m;
      int n;
    //sweep x axis for matches

   for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)     // the letter k is unclean and must be purged
    {
        for (m = 0; m < 5; m++)
        {
            for (n = 0; n < 5; n++)
            {

                if (n > 0)
                {
                    if (grid[n - 1, m, l] == grid[n, m, l] && xcombo < 6)
                    {

                        xcombo += 1;

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        switch (xcombo)
                        {
                            case 4:
                                Debug.Log("match 5" + cube[n - 1, m, l] + cube[n - 2, m, l] + cube[n - 3, m, l] + cube[n - 4, m, l] + cube[n - 5, m, l]);
                                   grid[n - 1, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                   grid[n - 2, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                   grid[n - 3, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                   grid[n - 4, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                   grid[n - 5, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                   xcombo = 0;
                                   refreshGrid();

                                break;
                            case 3:
                                Debug.Log("match 4" + cube[n - 1, j, l] + cube[n - 2, j, l] + cube[n - 3, j, l] + cube[n - 4, j, l]);
                                 grid[n - 1, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                 grid[n - 2, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                 grid[n - 3, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                 grid[n - 4, m, l] = randomNumber();

                                xcombo = 0;
                                refreshGrid();

                                break;
                            case 2:
                                Debug.Log("match 3" + cube[n - 1, j, l] + cube[n - 2, j, l] + cube[n - 3, j, l]);
                                  grid[n - 1, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                  grid[n - 2, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                  grid[n - 3, m, l] = randomNumber();
                                xcombo = 0;
                                refreshGrid();
                                break;
                        }
                        Debug.Log("combo" + xcombo);
                        xcombo = 0;
                        refreshGrid();

                    }

                }

            }
            n = 0;
        }
        m = 0;
        xcombo = 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: So you determined from logging/debugging that all three variables are being set to 5 at some point?

Comment: yeah its super wierd, i was using another 3 called i,j and k that i was using for the for loops in other methods and thought they were getting messed up somewhere else but l,m and n are getting set to 5 and theyre local to matchcheck()

Comment: it gives this error
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
(wrapper managed-to-managed) object:ElementAddr_3_8 (object,int,int,int)

Comment: Does it consistently give the same line when that error is thrown? Also, what is `refreshGrid()` doing?

Comment: Which line is it actually? The first occurence of `grid[...]` in the respective cycle?

Answer (score 1):

```
grid[n - 5
```

That and all the similar lines (except n-1) will result in negative numbers when n is low.

Also, your for loop starts n at 0, but you immediately check if it is greater than 0. Why not just start it at 1?